# Android Facebook (Something went wrong) Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, share

i am using the facebook sdk 3.5 to implement sharing dialog i can now successfully show a share dialog with link app name and description it now goes to facebook ...however when i press the share button it posts a message on toast with:

something went wrong please try again

**Here is how i use share dialog:**

```
FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder shareDialogBuilder = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MyClass.this)
                .setApplicationName("app name")
                .setName("Name")
                .setLink("my link");
                if (shareDialogBuilder.canPresent()) { 
                    shareDialogBuilder.build().present();
                    } else { 
                        Log.v("", "CAN_PRESENT() failed"); 
                    }
```

i read some related issues and checked on my link but it is working properly and called properly.. is there any way that i can log the error? what other issues might be causing this issue?

thank you.

Comment: your hashkey may be wrong

Comment: Please post your code on how you're using the share dialog.

Comment: @MingLi - i have edited my post.. thanks~ it says (Something went wrong please try again)

Comment: can you send your error status message

Comment: Just to sure, when you're calling setApplicationName, is it exactly the same name as what you have in your Facebook app settings?

Comment: yup it is the same. but i was thinking why the setApplicationName goes in the bottom part.?